# Simultaneous failure of 8x SSD's in raid 10

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, raid, software-raid, hardware-raid

My friend keeps arguing with me about putting SSD’s in raid vs HDD, I need to settle this. What are the odds of all the SSD’s failing vs HDD”s at once assuming they are from the same assembly line and time of manufacturing match?

At work here we see software raid have all 4x bad SMART status. Could this just be an issue with the controller, or the kernel managing the raid. Or is this a problem with the hardware itself?

Comment: I will also be adding a hotspare.

Comment: have they been checked and verified that they have the same firmware on each?

Answer (score 2):

The odds of a failure of identical SSD's failing in a RAID10 are higher than one might imagine as you are really relying on tiny differences in manufacturing to provide your robustness, compounded that when SSD drives fail they tend to fail catastrophically.

You would be better off to use different drives in each part of the array so they come from different factories and have different failure characteristics - but this is really little more than common sense.

Some references with respect of another incorrect poster as per his request for evidence -

RAID is available on my "bulk standard" consumer grade Samsung 840 EVO
SSD (and, of course, links show this is not atypical [here](http://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/minisite/SSD/global/html/about/whitepaper07.html) (samsung) and [here](http://ocz.com/consumer/download/firmware) *for OCD) and see the dump from my (Intel) SSD SMART request for a start) -

> smartctl -i /dev/sda smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841
>   [x86_64-linux-3.13.0-35-generic] (local build) Copyright (C) 2002-13,
>   Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org
>
> === START OF INFORMATION SECTION === Device Model:     Samsung SSD 840 EVO 500GB mSATA Serial Number:    S1KMNEAF100764Y LU WWN Device Id: 5
>   002538 844584d30 Firmware Version: EXT41B6Q User Capacity:
>   500,107,862,016 bytes [500 GB] Sector Size:      512 bytes
>   logical/physical Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device Device is:
>   Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall] ATA Version is:
>   ACS-2, ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4c SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0
>   Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s) Local Time is:    Sat Dec 27 20:34:11 2014
>   NZDT SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability. SMART
>   support is: Enabled

Software TRIM RAID Suport - See [here](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=1330071) and [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/508459/implementing-linux-fstrim-on-ssd-with-software-md-raid).

SSD's are prone to [failure well before the read/write cycles are up](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/ssd-reliability-failure-rate,2923.html), and typically do so catastrophically (ie the drive stops working, rather than goes read only from too many writes.)

Comment: By all due respect - how is this post of yours is settling the score  between the OP and his/her friend? Not to mention that SSD is still cutting-edge while HDD is known, old and trusted in homes and in the enterprise? Where am I wrong on SMART, or on TRIM, about less than 80% SSD capacity to be used ON SSDs or about anything else I wrote?

Comment: What you are describing is the lack of the SSD technology to predict failure - but please read my post. Failure is a defect, end of predicted service live is a published documentation. SSD technology do not currently have SMART.

Comment: The purpose of SU is technical information, not settling scores.  SSD's are not cutting edge, they are mainstream and starting to rival Hard drives in capacity although not price per gig (1tb drives are common in a 2.5" form factor) - for cutting edge look at HP's Memrister technology.   I'll add references rebutting your assertions in my post in a few minutes.

Comment: Please look at the OP's dilemma - Which one would you choose for a RAID 10 - SSD or HDD?

Comment: Can't answer this question - not enough information (ie how much data needs to be stored and whats the risk/speed requirements, bulk reads or lots of small files). SSD's have a lower failure rate the HDD's (about 1-2% per year as opposed to 5% - not when I say failure I mean failure, not end of useful life).   And Sorry, but only someone who lacks a grasp of risk mitigation would use drives all from the same batch for both halves of a RAID array when there are easily available alternatives.

Comment: As of today, December of 27, 2014 - HDD for RAID 10 no matter the use. Five years from now - oh well...

Answer (score 0):

The majority of SSD's do not support TRIM in RAID no matter if you use a high-end controller or kernel RAID. Then, SSD's appreciate less than about 80% storage allocation of the total capacity so the drive's firmware is able recondition the allocated data area by replacing higly used sections with new (unallocated) sections. If you use a journaling filesystem then the transparency between RAID and journaling gets more complicated for a kernel (software) RAID, and if you use a controller then some of this might be excluded, at least partially, when and how usage patterns are calculated inside the SSDs - provided that all the SSDs and the controller and the OS fully support each other.

I am only guessing here, but I would support YOUR argument against your friend's stance on SSD's versus HDD on RAID. I too prefer HDDs in RAID 1 and up for data redundancy, and SSD's for single drive config or at most RAID 0 where perfomance is the primary goal. Especially when using RAID 10 - perfomance is going to suffer no matter what you are using, but HDDs are going to be a better choice. SSD's are simply amazing at swappping or for paging, provided you allocate no more than 50% of their total storage capacity. When eventually the SSD [edit: wears out, instead of fails - fails means a defect, wears our means reaching a predictable end of service] due to really heavy swapping you only loose some swap or a Windows page file - replace the drive and keep going!

By the way, SMART is HDD, not SSD technology, and if your kernel RAID or controller is able to report on it to your OS that is stellar - but SMART has to do with the HDD's health, not with the OS or your config of RAID, or the controller itself.

I have no idea about the 'simultaneous failure of 8x' drive, but the answer for that must be somewhere along these lines.

Comment: Voted down because there are lots of dubious (false) statements and unsupported speculation in this post (including "RAID and TRIM", SMART is HDD not SSD technology, and it does not really answer the question - sorry.

Comment: Thank you - there is nothing more annoying but drive-by down voters, and you are NOT one of them. I appreciate that. Please let us see.

Comment: Actually SSDs have SMART attributes as well, and the lack of trim in many hardware raid implimentations is well documented.  Some *citations* would be nice.

Comment: I do not argue against the lack-of it, I argue for it. S.M.A.R.T for SSD as is now for HDD is a necessity to introduce SSD into an array just the way HDD is now. Of course SSD is the winner, SSD is going to overtake HDD, no contest. Only the fact some people suggest or truly believe that SSD is here and now on the same level. It is not, and their perseverance is a discredit to the potentials to the technological limits of SSD. Seriously - like comparing a kite to a jet fighter. SSD now is the kite, and HDD is the string to fly the thing.

Comment: "My friend keeps arguing with me about putting SSD’s in raid vs HDD, I need to settle this." Read the OP's post.

Comment: A SSD does not care about RAID. It either supports TRIM or it does not. The rest is up to the RAID controller/software.

Comment: Wrong. SSD trim command should come from the OS - but in case of journaling and RAID ,the rules change. Trim is not firmware or hardware or OS specific. It is OS specific to make the hardware understand what is required to maintain itself - look at Oracle Virtual box - there is a storage option to specify SSD hard-drive.

Comment: After running out of arguments - all it remains is keep building.

Comment: I do not understand the down-votes. If and where I am wrong - fine, I need to learn more - but at least please let me know!

Comment: It seems you’re misunderstanding something. TRIM is simply a feature a SSD can support. Whether a program or RAID controller or whatever sends the TRIM command is another matter altogether. Whether TRIM works in a RAID array is up to the controller, which has to forward the command to the appropriate array members. Journaling or filesystems are yet another different thing. TRIM is not self-maintenance. It is a command the host can send to the disk, specifying a block range which is to be marked as unused.

Comment: On trim I do not understand what I wrote differently from you. RAID and Journaling defeats its very purpose - after all once the command is sent data is not going into a recycle bin, it goes to null. So please tell me, what do I not understand about trim? There is no recovery, and the block where there was data before is now a clean slate. There are only three problems: the overhead of RAID, the records of a journaling file system, and the SSD latency (there is some if you like to believe). What makes you so sure that the individual SSD honors the facts - especially when they are 8-up?

Comment: (Another aside, see [Replying in comments](http://superuser.com/editing-help#comment-reply).)

Comment: Oh... Good point, thank you, I might indeed put my own spin on this. Unless the OP responds there is no way to tell, but a very good point, thank you!

Comment: Ok, cleaning up (deleting) my comments!